# Unable to retrieve CSRF cookie set by Django view via Android front-end

Tags: android, python, django, post, csrf

I am using Ion by Koush to get the cookie from a URL which is an endpont of my Django web application.

```
String urlStr = "http://example.herokuexampleapp.com/registration_id/";
URL url = null;
try {
url = new URL(urlStr);
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(),    url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
List<HttpCookie> cookielist =    Ion.getDefault(getApplicationContext()).getCookieMiddleware().getCookieManager().getCookieStore()
        .get(uri);
Log.e("cookielist",""+cookielist.toString());
String csrfToken = "";
for (HttpCookie cookie : cookielist) {
    if (cookie.getName().equals("csrftoken")) {
        csrfToken =  cookie.getValue();

    }

}
```

This code worked perfectly for a while. But then it automatically stopped detecting any cookie at all after a while! This didn't get fixed even after the ensure_csrf_cookie decorator was added to the Django view that is supposed to the send the CSRF cookie (just in case it was skipping it).

So my question is: why would CSRF cookies disappear, and what's a reliable way to ensure cookie retrieval? And if this cookie retreival method is not appropriate, then what is the best alternative to get the csrf token for request authentication?

P.S I don't want to use Apache HttpClient and other classes. They are no longer supported.